# Migrations from Netbeans to eclipse for large C++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans

How Can I migrate my large C++ project from Netbeans to Eclipse which include multiple flags,library etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/whatsnew/), it will help you migrate both from netbeans and from eclipse at the same time.

Comment: Hey can you please elaborate

Comment: Sorry for a vague suggestion, I'm a visual studio user and netbeans/eclipse do not come close when compared to MS Visual Studio. That's why I simply gave a suggestion to skip eclipse and just switch to visual studio. Perhaps, I'd quit my job and went elsewhere instead of using eclipse :) There was one eclipse based product thought that I didn't complain and it worked quite well: [ARM DS-5 Development Studio](https://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/ds-5/index.php)

Answer (score -1):

Follow This Steps...

1.In Eclipse, Go to File -> New -> Java Project

2.Give a name for your project and click finish to create your project

3.When the project is created find the source folder in NetBeans project, drag and drop all the source files from the NetBeans project to 'src' folder of your new created project in eclipse.

4.Move the java source files to respective package (if required)

Now you should be able to run your NetBeans project in Eclipse.

Comment: Its C++ project, I already tried that method but as I said there are many preprocessor flags,library path etc that makes migration task difficult